# Help developing a differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

So I'm just studying for my final, and doing some practice DE questions.

I have one that asks me to determine a DE given that we have \$100,000 principle being compounded continuously at 5%, but also being withdrawn at a rate of \$4000 per year.

I start with the standard cont. compound interest equation:

$$
A = Pe^{rt}
$$

But this is involving rates so I take the derivative of the above, and subtract the other rate.

$$
\frac{dA}{dt} = 5000e^{0.05t} - 4000
$$

From here I could integrate to find an eqn. for the amount in terms of t.

Am I on the right track here? I have a feeling I'm way off base here.

Comment: you are saying that it is compounded continously . Subtracting $4000$ doesn't make sense because that is depreciation in $1$ year . It is not being depreciated continously !

Comment: @ScubaSteve: Did they give five percent compounded (seems so from $r$, but you did not state that.

Comment: @ Amzoti Ah yeah they did. I'll put that in.

Comment: @ Trafalgar - the first part is being compounded continuously, the second part is flowing out yearly at 4000 per year... ahh.. we covered this stuff for like a single 1 hour lecture.. so i'm kindof lost

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have:

- $M(t)$ is the amount of money in the account at time $t$.
- The rate interest earned is proportional to the balance and constant $0.05$.
- The rate of withdrawals is constant at $4000$ per year.
- In words, rate of change =  rate of earning interest - rate of withdrawals.

As a DE, this becomes:

$$\dfrac{dM}{dt} = 0.05 M - 4000$$

This leads to the solution:

$$M(t) = c_1 e^{0.05 t} + 80000$$

You were given $M(0) = 100000$, so can find $c_1 = 20000$.

Comment: Great outline, set-up, and solution! +1

Comment: How did you get to M(t) from dM/dt? I'm confused as to where the 80,000 comes from, and as two how you found c sub 1.

Comment: The equation is separable, so we can write $\displaystyle  \int \dfrac{dm}{0.05 m - 4000} = \int dt$. So, you are just solving that integral. Clear?

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I'm having trouble solving that integral without my CAS though.

Comment: Ah ok I can integrate it and find an equivalent solution. But how does 20ln(0.05m - 4000) become 20ln(m - 80000) ?

Comment: Also, how am I to know that there's supposed to be a constant c in front of e? It's obvious that alone M(0) wouldn't equal 100,000, but where's the clue as to where c1 should be?

Comment: Take the exponential of both sides. Well, we have $$M(t) = c_1 e^{0.05 t} + 80000$$, when $t = 0$, we get $c_1 + 80000 = 100000$.

Comment: Ok got it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You are very welcome - regards

Answer (score 2):

It helps to take the time to define everything, including units

t = time in years from now.

A(t) = dollars in bank at time t; A(0)=100,000.

Instantaneous withdrawal rate = \$4000/year

Continuously compounded interest rate = 5%/year

Instantaneous rates are additive and can be considered separately. Make sure the units all match, though. If you receive interest on the bank balance, continuously compounded at an annual rate of 5%, then the loan bank account balance is instantaneously increasing at a rate of 5% of the total amount:
$$
   \frac{dA}{dt} = 0.05 A
$$
If you're also pulling money out at a constant instantaneous rate of \$4000 per year, then the final initial value equation is
$$
   \frac{dA}{dt} = 0.05A - 4,000,\;\;\; A(0)=100,000.
$$
To solve the equation,
$$
       \int_{100,000}^{A(t)}\frac{dA}{A-80,000} = \int_{0}^{t} 0.05 dt
$$
$$
         \ln |A(t)-80,000|-\ln|100,000-80,000| = 0.05t
$$
Moving $\ln(20,000)$ to the right side and exponentiating both sides gives
$$
               A(t) = 80,000+20,000e^{0.05t}.
$$
Here's a question for you: What should you replace $4,000$ with in order to make the account balance (a) decrease with time (b) stay constant with time? HINT: $\frac{dA}{dt}$ is identically $0$ if it is ever $0$; so, if $\frac{dA}{dt} \ne 0$, then it cannot change sign.

Comment: Minor terminology, it's not a loan but a savings account. But I get what you're getting at.

Comment: Ok. So how do I solve for A(t) from here?